# Getting blank page & apis are not getting called in agora-chat after integration of Agora wih laravel

Tags: laravel-8, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I have integrated agora using the instructions provided in the link :

https://www.agora.io/en/blog/build-a-scalable-video-chat-app-with-agora-laravel/

but , I am getting blank page after the integration is done on url : http://localhost/agora-chat.. Looks like agora apis are not getting called after the integration . Need support on this [Attached the screenshot of the blank page after integration]

Comment: Is laravel running in "local" environment? You can check this in your `.env` file. If there is still no error message, you can share the `laravel.log` file contents with us.

Comment: hi @shaedrich... Yes the laravel is running in my local environment ..

Comment: Okay, a blank page is somewhat unlikely when `APP_ENV=local`. What are the last lines in your `laravel.log`? Is `APP_DEBUG=true` and `LOG_LEVEL=debug` in your `.env`?

Comment: hi @shaedrich , /var/www/html/bpm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()